# com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, bootstrap-4, htmlunit

I am trying to browse http://taxtest.navajocountyaz.gov/Pages/WebForm1.aspx?p=1&apn=10301003B using Java code and the latest release of HTMLUnit (version 2.37.0, which I downloaded from a jar download website along with all its dependencies).

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
    public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("handleRefresh");
    }
});
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("http://taxtest.navajocountyaz.gov/Pages/WebForm1.aspx?p=1&apn=10301003B");
```

The last line of code throws the following exception:
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher (http://taxtest.navajocountyaz.gov/js/bootstrap.js#15)

How do I fix my Java code to be able to browse http://taxtest.navajocountyaz.gov/Pages/WebForm1.aspx?p=1&apn=10301003B ? I am only interested in extracting some numerical values from the web page.

Comment: Looks like a problem inside HtmlUnit itself. Please open an issue at github and I will have a look

Comment: Thanks RBRi for your reply. I just opened an issue at GitHub. Here is the link to it: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/127

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this as an HTMLUnit issue at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/127 , and RBRI has found a fix for it. I am posting the fix below:

Adding the following import statement:

```
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.*;
```

and adding the following code

```
    webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new SilentJavaScriptErrorListener());
```

did fix the problem.

Thank you very much RBRI for your help.